# Apply Moment.js to the date in my c # loop

Tags: javascript, c#, loops, momentjs

I want to Apply Moment.js to the date in my c# loop, but the function only uses the first value of ".pu_date" to change the other values :

C#:

```
@foreach( var u in Model.Users)
{
<span class="pu_date"> @u.Date</span> @* '15/08/2017 09:00:00' *@
}
```

JS:

```
$('.pu_date').text(moment($('.pu_date').text(), "DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm:ss").fromNow());
```

Result:

```
7 days
7 days
7 days
```

Instead of :

```
7 days
16 days
20 days
```

Comment: This is nothing to do with C#, it would be better to post the final render of HTML rather the razor syntax.

Answer (score 2):

You have to get the date from each element

```
$( ".pu_date" ).each(function( index ) {
    $( this ).text( moment($( this ).text(), "DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm:ss").fromNow());
});
```

Comment: @DeteR Now you return the favor and mark my answer as the correct answer. This is the way this community works. Welcome to Stackoverflow